# Laravel and Ajax Like system is saving multiple record of like to likes table

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Trying to send create a like system in my laravel app with ajax , it works but when sending data to the likes table , it sends duplicates of the same like , about 5 of them , i dont know why , when i do the same like function without the ajax , it works just fine without no problems , here's my code

BLADE

```
 <div class="container">

            @if ( auth()->user()->hasLiked($activity))
            <a href="{{ route('reply.unlike', ['id' => $activity->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Unlike</a>

            @else

            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs likeMain">
                <input type="hidden" class="id" value="{{ $activity->id }}">
                <input type="hidden" class="user-id" value="{{ $activity->user_id }}">
                Like
            </a>
            @endif
            
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });

                    $('.likeMain').click(function () {
                        var ActID = $('.id').val();
                        var userss = $('.user-id').val();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/replylike',
                            data: {
                                ActID: ActID,
                                userss: userss
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                             console.log(data)
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

            </script>
        </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function likeReply(Request $request) 
  {
    Like::create([
     'likeable_id' => $request->ActID,
     'likeable_type' => 'App\Activity',
    'user_id' => Auth::id()
  ]);

Session::flash('success', 'You Liked the activity');

return redirect()->back();
}
```

ROUTE

```
  Route::post('/replylike', [
      'uses' => 'LikeController@LikeReply',
      'as' => 'reply.like'
  ]);
```

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `return redirect()->back()` then try it again

Comment: i just did , but same thing